# Investigate strange message from syslog@stock

Tags: linux, centos, ssh

I've noticed that when I'm logged into my server I sometimes get spammed a message from syslog@stock. On this server I am running a website built with Laravel and a Teamspeak 3 server running with over 20 active users.

The messages I get are

```
Message from syslogd@stock at Jul 25 17:42:13 ...
 t of memory [4188]

Message from syslogd@stock at Jul 25 17:42:13 ...
 t of memory [4194]

Message from syslogd@stock at Jul 25 17:42:14 ...
 t of memory [4202]

Message from syslogd@stock at Jul 25 17:42:14 ...
 t of memory [4208]

Message from syslogd@stock at Jul 25 17:42:15 ...
 t of memory [4214]

Message from syslogd@stock at Jul 25 17:42:15 ...
 t of memory [4224]

Message from syslogd@stock at Jul 25 17:42:15 ...
 t of memory [4233]

Message from syslogd@stock at Jul 25 17:42:16 ...
 t of memory [4241]
```

I'm puzzled on what these messages mean.

Running CentOS @ 32GB Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1245 V2 @ 3.40GHz

`free -m`

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         32070      15338      16732          0        409       5386
-/+ buffers/cache:       9541      22528
Swap:         1021          0       1021
```

Comment: It appears as though the system thinks you're ***Out of memory***. Can you provide the output of `free -m`

Comment: Added that in the edit

Comment: Is `stock` the hostname of this machine?

Comment: No, stock isn't the hostname.

Comment: Does the name `stock` appear in your `/etc/hosts`?  What happens if you do `ping stock`?

Comment: these messages should also be logged to files in /var/log/ -- you may find IP address of source host there

Comment: I ran into such an issue right now. Can you share your expereince? We have free mem 21378 out of total 129015.

Comment: @caot Never did find a solution but I'm long past it,

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I found on the issue for my case. `ulimit -a` can identify `virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) 10485760`. If any process has a 
virtual memory reaching or trying to go beyound the limit, it will broadcast 
the mentioned issue as that in the question. `htop` is more helpful than `top`.

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 1031979
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 104
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) 10485760
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```